# Error in pic(d, multi2di(tree, random = FALSE)) : missing data in 'x'

Tags: r, phylogeny

I am getting the following error message why I try to use phyl.pairedttest()

```
Error in pic(d, multi2di(tree, random = FALSE)) : missing data in 'x'
```

The code is written as follows:

```
phyl.pairedttest(Tree, DataSet$Male, DataSet$Female)
```

Where I am trying to use a phylogenetic paired t-test to compare male and female traits. I checked if the species names in the tree and those in the dataset, using the name.check() function, and the row names are the same as the species names in the tree. Any idea as to how to resolve this issue?

Comment: We will need a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that generates the error in order to answer your question.